Sent to Wrong address
Someone gave me the wrong address to send the bitcoins to on my cash app.  Now I’ve lost everything. Can I get it back? I’ve contacted Cash app they said that once it is cashed out they have no way to track it. I’ve tried searching for it but can not find it.
